# Software/CMS for a subscription service website

Tags: web-development, wordpress

I have a reasonable amount of experience in creating WordPress websites, plus I've made a couple of specific websites from scratch using html/css/js.

However, I'd like to build a website for a monthly subscription delivery service I'm thinking of launching, and I'm wondering whether it's possible to create it just in WordPress (or any other CMS) using the right add-ons or if I'll need something more involved.  I'm willing to pay someone to do the bits I can't do if necessary.

The website will need to:

1. Advertise and describe the service (no problems with WordPress for this one!).
2. Allow customers to sign up for a monthly/3-month/annual subscription.
3. Take payment for the subscriptions (ideally through something like Stripe).
4. Let the customer choose from a set of categories (one or multiple) for their subscription, and update their preferences as necessary.
5. Ideally allow me to manage the catalogue of different items I have in stock for delivery each month (although this can be back-end only as the customer won't see this).
6. Each month, provide the customer with a random choice of 3 of the items in stock to choose from for delivery.

I think #6 will be hardest to implement...

Looking forward to hearing your tips and suggestions! :)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about recommending software that meets specific requirements – not the other way around. For details, see [Are “Can I use X for Y” questions on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2816/185) I've slightly modified the title to reflect that – and hope you're open for recommendations other than WP as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Izzy :)  I'm happy for any suggestions at all!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look at Shopify which is a big name ecommerce platform.

I'm not sure if you can do #6 on it though, but you could ask on the Shopify community website.